# Tools to convert from 16-bit RGB to 24-bit RGB and vice versa

Tags: colors, lcd, color-depth

Are there any image editing or research tools, hopefully OSS, which will allow me to:

- map colors (images) from 16-bit RGB (565) to 24-bit RGB (888) space or vice versa
- save files in PNG, GIF, or JPEG
- give user the ability to control how colors are mapped from 16-bit space to 24-bit space.

I found one issue that discusses something similar but I'm hoping I'll be able to run these tests without writing any code.
 [convert 24bit RGB to ARGB16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1553502/981380)

Here's a little background for this request.

I'm working on a project evaluating an LCD display panel.  The native bit depth of the panel is 24-bits (RGB 888) and it is currently available on an evaluation kit that uses an LCD controller that supports 24-bit output only.

The LCD controller on the product for which this panel is being evaluated only supports 16-bit output (RGB 565).  In the final design the remaining bits for each color channel on the panel will be connected in some way.

The evaluation kit does not take RGB inputs (as mentioned above it only takes PNG, JPEG, or GIF). I'm looking for a way to create 16-bit and 24-bit RGB files which will then be converted to a PNG.   By manipulating the values of the R, G and B channels in the source files (16-bit and 24-bit) I want to compare the difference between driving a 24-bit display with 24-bits of color and 16-bits of color (extended to 24-bits).

I'd also be interested in learning about others experiences with this sort of evaluation and the sanity of my proposed test methodology.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had posted this question on the graphic design stack exchange and received a few comments and answers that were helpful.

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/12648/8539